# Replace html text in javascript include

Tags: php, javascript, html

i've got this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://xy.com/something.js"></script>
```

in my php/html file. It includes the whole something.js file.
In this file, there are lines like with "document.write..." that are writing some text on my page.

Is it possible to replace a string that is included from this js file in my php document? I can't change the js file (I don't have access to it).

**More information:**

The .js file looks like this:

```
...
var msg = '';
msg +='<b>mystring1</b><br/><i>mystring2</i>';
document.write(msg);
...
```

My php file includes the js file. I wanna change the mystring2 to myteststring in PHP. Is this possible? How?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this cleanly.

If the .js file is calling `document.write()` *inline* and it doesn't access any external variables or functions you really don't have any control over it. You could perhaps redefine `document.write()` but that's ugly.

I suggest you either maintain your own copy of that .js file or change the document a second time using another script executed from the `window.onload` event.